# Property implementation must have declaration in interface

Tags: ios

When I try to compile this I get this error. What do I need to add for the property declaration in the interface? If textBox is an instance variable, why does it need to be declared as a property?

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TNRViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *textBox;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "TNRViewController.h"

@implementation TNRViewController
@synthesize textBox;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [textBox release];
    [label release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    NSString *Name = textBox.text;
    NSString *Output = Nil;
    Output = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ says: Hello World!", Name];
    label.text = Output;
    [Output release];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    [textBox resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textBox needs to be declared as a property because you are @synthesizing it in your implementation.

You need to either:

1. Add the @property declaration for textBox in your interface.
2. OR, You could remove the @sythesize line from your implementation if you don't plan on needing the setter/getter methods.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It worked after removing the @synthesize line.

Answer (score 1):

by writing `@synthesize textBox` in your implementation the compiler generates 2 methods for you automatically.

```
-(UITextField*)textBox
-(void)setTextBox:(UITextField *)textBox
```

To be accessed these need to be defined in the class' interface. Objective-C for the iPhone has a nifty shortcut for declaring these two methods, the `@property` directive. You can also include information about how the variable should be stored in this directive.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * textBox
```

Would give you your IBOutlet for a text field. It is also a stand in for the 2 methods above. It tells us that the textBox is retained by your class. By always using the setter and getter methods for a variable you can avoid releasing an object and referencing the instance variable later, when it may not be safe. It is best practise to do this. You would access the text field from within your class by doing

```
[self.textBox setText:@"aString"];
self.textBox.text = @"aString";
```

(the lines above are equivalent)

Comment: Besides the 2 accessors, `@synthesize` also generates an instance variable declaration if you don't have your own declaration. This means that once you get used to `@property` and `@synthesize`, you usually won't write your own variable declarations anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened when I added a pod. I ended up deleting a updating my pod file and it fixed the error.